# Cloudbuild to trigger Github merge to master branch

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have a Google Cloudbuild pipeline, that tests the code committed to the dev branch of my Github repo, and deploys the code to the dev environment. I want to add another step to the pipeline, which would merge my dev branch with the prod branch, upon successful deployment to the dev environment. Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can do that in your 'cloudbuild.yaml' (or another name) file which is 'executed' by the Cloud Build trigger.

In my experience you will need a pair of keys - the public key should be in GitHub, the private key value - stored as a secret in the Secret Manager.

Thus, in the yaml file you might need to use (change according to your case, do not use like this):

```
  volumes:
  - name: 'ssh'
    path: /root/.ssh
```

So far:

1. get the private key (from the secret) and save it as a a file `/root/.ssh/github` by using something like `gcloud secrets versions access latest ...`
2. change permissions `chmod 600 /root/.ssh/github`
3. create a config file:

```
cat <<EOF >/root/.ssh/config
Hostname github.com
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/github
EOF
```

4. save GitHub public key to a known_hosts file `ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts`

After that, you (actually your Cloud Build service account using provided credentials) can do with GitHub repository whatever is required (subject to permissions granted in GitHub) using ordinary `git` commands.